Don't have the option to start emulator from VS Code
While setting up the emulator with Android Studio Koala, I noticed that from VS Code I don't have the option to fire up the emulator so that it immediately turns on from VS Code. It doesn't show me any device, and when I type in Command Palette > Flutter: launch emulator, nothing.
I searched the internet but found nothing because everyone has it. flutter doctor says everything is fine. In Android Studio SDK tools also installed.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
